# how to rearrange my array of object in js

Tags: javascript, reduce

> > This is my first data set that needs to be rearranged

```
const data = [
{
  "title": "report",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby":"ramhari",
  "filename":"johnrepr",
  "belongs to":"johncena"
 },
  {
  "title": "cv",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby":"ramhari",
  "filename":"alex",
  "belongs to":"alexharper"
},
{
   "title": "cv",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby": "ramhari",
  "filename": "shyamcv",
  "belongs to": "shyamsundar"
},
{
  "title": "exam",
  "id": 17,
  "upload-by":'ram',
  "filename": "roha-nexam",
  "belongs to": "rohan"
},
{ "title": "report",
  "id": 17,
  "upload-by": "ram",
  "filename": "bincv",
  "belongs to": "binodkkhatri"
},
{
   "title": "exam",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby": "ganesh",
  "filename": "sandeshexam",
  "belongs to": "sandeshuprety"
},
```

> and i want to rearrange my data with that should have one property title :'CV' and rest of the other data that have same title should be inside rows property which is an array. the structure will be  like this
> `

```
const mynewdata=[
{title:'cv',rows:[{},{},{}]},
{title:'report',rows:[{},{},{}],
{title:"exam",rows:[{},{},{}]}
]`;
```

> so i here the code i tried

```
   

    const res = data.reduce((grouped,single)=>{
       const key = single.title;    //this is my title
       const newobj = {title:key,rows:[single]} //creating new object which i needed it to be
       grouped.lenght >=0 ? 
       grouped.filter((group)=>{
       return group.title===key ? group.rows.push({single}) : grouped.push(newobj)
       }):grouped.push(newobj)//false condition
      return grouped;
    },[])
```

> OUTPUT:

```
Output:
[
  { title: 'report', rows: [ [Object] ] },
  { title: 'CV', rows: [ [Object] ] },
  { title: 'CV', rows: [ [Object] ] },
  { title: 'exam', rows: [ [Object] ] },
  { title: 'report', rows: [ [Object] ] },
  { title: 'exam', rows: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

> the CV and exam are repeating it should be only one and rest other data should be in array 'rows' inside there corresponding title.
> even if the grouped.length >=0 ? is true, the false condition is running ???

Comment: You have a typo in grouped.length >= 0. Not sure if that will solve your issue but it’s a place to start. It looks like you know what you’re doing with your logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to give you the output you are looking for:

```js
// First group the data by titles
let groups = data.reduce((a, i) => {
  a[i.title] = a[i.title] || [];
  a[i.title].push(i);
  return a;
}, {});

// Construct the new data array from the groups
let mynewdata = Object.keys(groups).map(key => ({
  title: key,
  rows: groups[key]
}))

console.log(mynewdata)

// Or a simpler method using Object.values and reduce.  Excludes extra title from rows object.
let mynewdata2 = Object.values(data.reduce((a, { title, ...rest }) => {
  a[title] = a[title] || { title, rows: [] }
  a[title].rows.push(rest)
  return a
}, {}))

console.log(mynewdata2)
```

```html
<script>
  const data = [{
      "title": "report",
      "id": 17,
      "uploadby": "ramhari",
      "filename": "johnrepr",
      "belongs to": "johncena"
    },
    {
      "title": "cv",
      "id": 17,
      "uploadby": "ramhari",
      "filename": "alex",
      "belongs to": "alexharper"
    },
    {
      "title": "cv",
      "id": 17,
      "uploadby": "ramhari",
      "filename": "shyamcv",
      "belongs to": "shyamsundar"
    },
    {
      "title": "exam",
      "id": 17,
      "upload-by": 'ram',
      "filename": "roha-nexam",
      "belongs to": "rohan"
    },
    {
      "title": "report",
      "id": 17,
      "upload-by": "ram",
      "filename": "bincv",
      "belongs to": "binodkkhatri"
    },
    {
      "title": "exam",
      "id": 17,
      "uploadby": "ganesh",
      "filename": "sandeshexam",
      "belongs to": "sandeshuprety"
    }
  ]
</script>
```

**Edit**

Added a simpler method using a single `reduce` function which also excludes the extra `title` property from `rows`

Answer (score 0):

Add all the titles to a set, that way you won't have duplicates. Then create an entry (title, rows) for each of these titles in the `myNewData` array. Iterate through your original `data` array and for each title that matches a title in `myNewData`, push the rest of its values (minus `title`) into the `rows` array for that title.

```
const data = [
{
  "title": "report",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby":"ramhari",
  "filename":"johnrepr",
  "belongs to":"johncena"
 },
  {
  "title": "cv",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby":"ramhari",
  "filename":"alex",
  "belongs to":"alexharper"
},
{
   "title": "cv",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby": "ramhari",
  "filename": "shyamcv",
  "belongs to": "shyamsundar"
},
{
  "title": "exam",
  "id": 17,
  "upload-by":'ram',
  "filename": "roha-nexam",
  "belongs to": "rohan"
},
{ "title": "report",
  "id": 17,
  "upload-by": "ram",
  "filename": "bincv",
  "belongs to": "binodkkhatri"
},
{
   "title": "exam",
  "id": 17,
  "uploadby": "ganesh",
  "filename": "sandeshexam",
  "belongs to": "sandeshuprety"
}]

const titles = new Set();
const myNewData = []
data.map(obj => {
  if (!titles.has(obj.title)) {
    titles.add(obj.title)
  }
})

titles.forEach(title =>
  {  const rows = []
  data.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.title === title) {
      delete entry.title
      rows.push(entry)
    }
  })
  {
     myNewData.push( {
      title,
      rows
    })
  }}
)

console.log(myNewData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the popular utility libraries have a `groupBy` function which turns an array into an object grouping all the elements by a key generated by a function supplied.  It's easy enough to write our own.  Using one, we easily convert to this format:

```js
{
  report: [
    {title: "report", id: 17, uploadby: "ramhari", filename: "johnrepr", "belongs to": "johncena"}, 
    {title: "report", id: 17, "upload-by": "ram", filename: "bincv", "belongs to": "binodkkhatri"}
  ], 
  cv: [
    {title: "cv", id: 17, uploadby: "ramhari", filename: "alex", "belongs to": "alexharper"}, 
    {title: "cv", id: 17, uploadby: "ramhari", filename: "shyamcv", "belongs to": "shyamsundar"}
  ], 
  exam: [
    {title: "exam", id: 17, "upload-by": "ram", filename: "roha-nexam", "belongs to": "rohan"}, 
    {title: "exam", id: 17, uploadby: "ganesh", filename: "sandeshexam", "belongs to": "sandeshuprety"}
  ]
}
```

Then after a conversion of this into a list of object entries we can turn these into your format.  The code ends up fairly simple:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a[k] = a[k] || []), (a[k] .push (x)), a), {})

const reformat = (xs) => 
  Object .entries (groupBy (x => x.title) (xs)) .map (([title, rows]) => ({title, rows}))


const data = [{title: "report", id: 17, uploadby: "ramhari", filename: "johnrepr", "belongs to": "johncena"}, {title: "cv", id: 17, uploadby: "ramhari", filename: "alex", "belongs to": "alexharper"}, {title: "cv", id: 17, uploadby: "ramhari", filename: "shyamcv", "belongs to": "shyamsundar"}, {title: "exam", id: 17, "upload-by": "ram", filename: "roha-nexam", "belongs to": "rohan"}, {title: "report", id: 17, "upload-by": "ram", filename: "bincv", "belongs to": "binodkkhatri"}, {title: "exam", id: 17, uploadby: "ganesh", filename: "sandeshexam", "belongs to": "sandeshuprety"}]

console .log (reformat (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```